# ASP.NET - script and css compression

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css, compression

Is there any native compression (for javascript/css files) available in ASP.NET?

Comment: what kind of compression: minification/packing or gzip/deflate?

Comment: not sure of the difference between minification/packing and gzip/deflate.  what i'm looking for is some native way for asp.net to compress script and css files so the actual files that are requested from server are smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the appendix of [Professional ASP.NET 3.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470187573) Scott Hanselman talks about [Packer for .NET](http://svn.offwhite.net/trac/SmallSharpTools.Packer/wiki).  This will integrate with MSBuild and pack javascript files for production deployments etc.

Comment: It seems we posted the same answer at the same time :-)

Comment: Looks like Packer is the closest thing that comes to native compression in .NET.

Comment: On Packer page there is a section "Packer versus JSMin" which says that JSMin can be more efficient than Packer.  On Yahoo Compressor page (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) it states that Yahoo compressor is more efficient than JSMin, so it looks like Yahoo compressor might be a good candidate even though its not native to .NET environment.

Comment: From Packer's website: "While Packer can created a much smaller output file it can be more problematic with packing JavaScript that does not conform to a strict syntax"...  Sounds scary, like it might mangle my javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Try Chirpy. It mashes, minifies, and validates your javascript, stylesheet, and dotless files.
You can use YUI Compressor or Google Closure Compiler.

http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

Or, for more info, check out:

http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/22/visual-studio-add-in-for-dotless-js-and-css-files/

Comment: Hey Weirdlover! this Chirpy thing looks amazing. is it possible also to make it compress the files at runtime ? i mean that in each request the server will compress the specified files (in the chirp.config) and return the minified mashed version in the response... posible?

Comment: Hey Dan -- we're building something like that. But, in the meantime, you can check out SquishIt, Combres, or you can futz with this rusty wheel: http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/10/zcontroller-asp-net-mvc-controller-fo-your-scripts-styles-images/

Comment: SquishIt & Combres looks nice but it doesn't seem to have too many downloads / community support yet... any idea when's the next version with that feature ? thanks!

Comment: I used to use Combres, and though it works well, Chirpy is far superior. No more runtime overhead... It's just frigging amazing.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Packer](http://smallsharptools.com/Projects/Packer/).

This utlity supports JavaScript compression and /or "minifying", and CSS "minifying".

It's available as a command line utility or also as an MSBuild task.
This way you can integrate it into your build process / Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 1):

There is Gzip/Deflate compression support in IIS compatible with all modern browsers except IE6. For IIS 7 check this page: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression

Answer (score 1):

Further to other answers and comments, you can use Yahoo!'s [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and make it an [MSBuild Task](http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/05/how-to-create-a-yui-compressor-msbuild-task/) to integration it into your build and deployment process.

Answer (score 1):

Try [StyleManager](http://www.gstylemanager.com) for CSS combination and minification. It uses YUI Compressor under-the-hood.

Its usage is a lot like asp.net's ScriptManager, so it's quick to get used to. It's easy to add to your project too, only takes a minute.

Most importantly - it combines your CSS files too. So instead of having like 10 CSS files to download it'll just be 1, which will also be compressed etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have written something to do this for me, you can download it here:
http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2009/12/10/Javascript-runtime-compilation-using-AspNet-and-Googles-Closure-Compiler.aspx

It uses Google's closure compiler which is pretty awesome.

Thanks

Guido

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way:
Use MVC. 
Process js|css content via MVC controller's actions.
Combine multiple files into one. 
Minify and obfuscate script|css on fly before it stored in cache. 
Cache results. 
Use CacheDependency. 
Enable gzip for dynamic content. 
Enable gzip before cache feature.

Everything can be done just by adding custom attributes on action methods, using [ASP.NET MVC Js/Css Composer/Compressor](http://compose.codeplex.com).

Sample:

```
public class JsController : Controller
{
    [Utility.Processors.JsCompress]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
    public ActionResult Jquery()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can derive from CustomTextPostProcessingAttribute and make your own postprocessing for any type of text content, you need.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned something today: you can run [JavaScript via windows console](http://www.phpied.com/cssminjs-in-windows-shell/). I'm a fan of cssmin.js; so, this plus windows console = win! All you have to do is download cssmin.js, put it in a folder on your web project and add the following post-build event in Visual Studio:

```
type "$(ProjectDir)css\*.css" | cscript //NoLogo "$(SolutionDir)tools\cssmin.js" > "$(ProjectDir)css\core.min.css"
```

Doing this keeps you from having to edit your project [as ajaxmin would have you to do](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start).